# Timestamp Column from Joined Table Becomes String

Tags: activerecord

I have a table named `subs` which has many `articles`.  The `articles` table has a timestamp column called `published`.

```
Sub.select( "subs.*,MAX(articles.published) published").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN articles ON subs.id=articles.sub_id").group("subs.id").first.published.class
=> String
Article.select("max(published) published").group("id").first.published.class
=>  ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

I want to get an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object back from the first query.

Comment: Ever figure out how to deal with this? I'm running into this same issue right now...

Comment: no,I used a extra query statement to fetch the timestamp column

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 3**

Rails determines how to type cast attributes based on their database column definitions.  For example, say you have a `created_at` method on your `Sub` model.  When a record is loaded `read_attribute` is used ([ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb)).  This uses `type_cast_attribute` which determines how to cast the value based on the column info.  For example, if you are using PostgreSQL it may use:

```
Sub.columns.detect { |c| c.name == "created_at" }.type_cast_code("v")
=> "ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn.string_to_time(v)"
```

But Rails doesn't know what to do with columns that aren't on the `Sub` model.  So it just gives back a `String`.  If you need to work with a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object, you can cast the value with:

```
published = Sub.select( "subs.*,MAX(articles.published) published").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN articles ON subs.id=articles.sub_id").group("subs.id").first.published
published.present? ? Time.zone.parse(published) : nil
```

**Rails 4**

In Rails 4, Rails is smarter about this kind of type-casting.  When the SQL is executed, [`ActiveRecord::Result`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb) is created and the `column_types` are passed to the initializer.  In your example `Sub.select` query, the `published` column would be cast as a `Time` object.